# R: Create frequency table with positive test results

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have an example dataframe with 4 columns. It has a column with birdspecies names and results from 3 different tests. If there is a number in the Test columns, then that means the test is positive.

```
> df
    Birdspecies Test1   Test2  Test3
1     Blackbird   ND     29     NA
2     Blackbird   31.1   ND/ND  NA
3     Blackbird   35.5   NA     NA
4     Blackbird   36.6   31     NA
5    Bluethroat   NA     NA     NA
6    Bluethroat   NA     40     NA
7    Bluethroat   34     34     CL
8  Feral pigeon   34.9   35     NA
9  Feral pigeon   34     NA     NA
10  Tufted Duck   NA     39     NA
```

I want to modify this dataframe into something like this:

```
 Birdspecies   Total Test1 Test2 Test3
1    Blackbird     4    3    2     0
2   Bluethroat     3    1    2     0
3 Feral pigeon     2    2    1     0
4  Tufted Duck     1    0    1     0
```

The first column with birdspecies is now collapsed and the "Total" column shows the total frequency of each birdspecies. The test columns show the frequencies of each positive test result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below code should help:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 = df %>% 
  mutate(Count = 1) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Test1,Test2,Test3),funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Test1,Test2,Test3),funs(ifelse(is.na(.),0,1))) %>% 
  group_by(Birdspecies) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

Let me know if it works. It gives same output as your desired output.

Comment: Your code does give the desired output for the example data, but I made a small mistake in my post. My actual data has empty cells, text such as "ND" and the positive numeric values. When I use your code on my actual data I get the same numeric value in every column.

Comment: To clarify: The counted frequencies are sums of everything (cells with text and cells with numeric values). Do you know how to exclude cells with text from the sum?

Comment: @KakSchoen, I have updated the code, ```as.numeric``` will convert all characters to ```NA``` which should solve your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You could use data.table package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c(.(Total = .N), lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(as.numeric(x), na.rm = T))), Birdspecies]
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
want <- df
want[, 2:4] <- lapply(want[, 2:4], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1))
want <- aggregate(cbind(Test1, Test2, Test3) ~ Birdspecies, want, sum)
want$Total <- tapply(df$Birdspecies, df$Birdspecies, length)
want

# Birdspecies Test1 Test2 Test3 Total
# 1    Blackbird     3     2     0     4
# 2   Bluethroat     1     2     0     3
# 3 Feral pigeon     2     1     0     2
# 4  Tufted Duck     0     1     0     1
```